# Why in default installation of apache in debian and ubuntu cgi-bin directory is in /usr/lib

Tags: apache, ubuntu, debian, cgi-bin

Well, the main question is in the title.
Why in default Apache installation in Debian and Ubuntu the **cgi-bin** directory is in **/usr/lib/cgi-bin** not for example in **/var/www/cgi-bin**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because that's what the [relevant section](http://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-customized-programs.html#s-web-appl) of Debian Policy Manual requires. The [Debian Policy](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-scope.html) document in general describes the policy requirements what each Debian Linux distribution and each package must conform to.

Comment: Thank's for you answer. I think that this should be enough for information. But do you know WHY debian policy says recommends this directory and not the other (/usr/local/lib) or /var/www/cgi-bin for example

Comment: Ah yes, because of security reasons. CGI scripts need extra attention when it comes to web security. Having the cgi-bin directory separated from the WWW root directory (/var/www) enables the more secure setup of script aliased CGI. This limits CGI execution permissions to special directories. See [this](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/20729/is-it-dangerous-to-serve-executable-cgi-files-in-public-folder) answer, it probably is a more detailed description for the issue.